# Drop a row and column at the same time Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe which is something like this

```
Victim Sex       Female    Male  Unknown
Perpetrator Sex                         
Female            10850   37618       24
Male              99354  299781       92
Unknown           33068  156545      148
```

I'm planning to drop both the row indexed as `'Unknown'` and the column named `'Unknown`'. I know how to drop a row and a column but I was wondering whether you could drop a row and a column at the same time in pandas? If yes, how could it be done?

Comment: From the answers, it seems it's not possible to drop (using `.drop()`) rows and columns at once (your question title), but it's possible to select at once the rows and columns you want to keep, using `.difference()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the job, however it's not really at the same time, but no intermediate object is returned to you.

```
df.drop("Unknown", axis=1).drop("Unknown", axis=0)
```

So for a concrete Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['A', 'B'], index=['C','D'])
print(df)
   A  B
C  1  2
D  3  4
```

the call

```
df.drop('B', axis=1).drop('C', axis=0)
```

returns

```
   A
D  3
```

Answer (score 5):

I think closest `'at the same time'` is select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
print (df.index.difference(['Unknown']))
Index(['Female', 'Male'], dtype='object')

print (df.columns.difference(['Unknown']))
Index(['Female', 'Male'], dtype='object')

df = df.loc[df.index.difference(['Unknown']), df.columns.difference(['Unknown'])]
print (df)
Victim Sex       Female    Male
Perpetrator Sex                
Female            10850   37618
Male              99354  299781
```

Comment: +1, but it seems this answer really says "*It's not possible to drop simultaneously, but it's possible to select what you want to keep at once*".

Answer (score 3):

You can delete columns and rows at the same time in one line just with their position. For example, if you want delete column 2,3 and 5 and at the same time if you want to remove index 0,1 and 3 along with the last row of the dataframe, you can do this by following,

```
df.drop(df.columns[[2,3,5]], axis = 1).drop(df.index[[0,1,3,-1]])
```